# Sharing scripts that require a virtualenv to be activated

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper installed on a shared Linux server with default settings (virtualenvs are in ~/.virtualenvs).  I have several Python scripts that can only be run when the correct virtualenv is activated.

Now I want to **share** those scripts with other users on the server, but without requiring them to know anything about virtualenv...  so they can run `python scriptname` or `./scriptname` and the script will run with the libraries available in my virtualenv.

What's the cleanest way to do this?  I've toyed with a few options (like changing the shebang line to point at the virtualenv provided interpreter), but they seem quite inflexible.  Any suggestions?

---

**Edit:** This is a development server where several other people have accounts.  However, none of them are Python programmers (I'm currently trying to convert them).  I just want to make it easy for them to run these scripts and possibly inspect their logic, without exposing non-Pythonistas to environment details.  Thanks.

Comment: A virtualenv is for the developer's needs. To test things in an isolated invironment, test dependancies, etc. If you distribute it, you shuold be able to just package it up like any other python script/module and not require a virtualenv on their end. 

What is it in the virtualenv that's specific to this script that can't be done system-wide for an end user?

Comment: @rharding -- I'm not deploying the scripts, just making them available for other users on the server.

Comment: Please consider accepting Chris Dukes' answer instead, The one provided by jcdyer doesn't answer the issue (and the author agreed that it isn't a good answer), while the other explains the issue well plus is a quick reference to the virtualenv shebang - question I was trying to answer when finding this topic. You might help others by accepting the most plusvoted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's only on one server, then flexibility is irrelevant.  Modify the shebang.  If you're worried about that, make a packaged, installed copy on the dev server that doesn't use the virtualenv.  Once it's out of develepment, whether that's for local users or users in guatemala, virtualenv is no longer the right tool.

Comment: Thanks ... what is the right tool for production then?

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer to this problem.

Comment: Agreed.  I don't stand by this answer anymore.

Answer (score 106):

Use the following magic(5) at the start of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Change which virtualenv is active and it'll use the python from that virtualenv.
Deactivate the virtualenv, it still runs.

Comment: A virtualenv CHANGES the /usr/bin/env python to point to your virtualenv python. So this is the right way to go

Comment: Thanks @JonasGröger, this explanation was the missing block in my understanding.

Answer (score 6):

I would vote for adding a shebang line in `scriptname` pointing to the correct virtualenv python. You just tell your users the full path to `scriptname` (or put it in their PATH), and they don't even need to know it is a Python script.

If your users are programmers, then I don't see why you wouldn't want them to know/learn about virtualenv.

Comment: Actually, I think I agree with this second paragraph.  Virtualenv is an awesome tool.  If you're trying to convert other programmers, show it to them.  It's easy to use, and it does cool things.

Comment: I disagree with the second paragraph though. Programmer who have not converted to Python yet, wont spend the effort to read about virtualenv. It seems easy for Python-converts because they have spent (invested) an hour or two playing with virtualenv until they get used to the idea and can use it. That investment is a barrier.